# Converting .docx/.doc files to .pdf in .Net Core

Tags: node.js, pdf, asp.net-core, ms-word, .net-core

I am trying to convert MS Word files (*.docx/*.doc) to *.pdf file but didn't find any .net core package to do so.

Then I thought to use Node.js package for the same and to run it inside my .Net Core app. I tried [node-msoffice-pdf](https://github.com/skmp/node-msoffice-pdf)  node package. I first created a sample Node app just to test if this package works but when I run it, I get following error:

```
D:\Projects\test\node_modules\edge\lib\edge.js:169
    return edge.initializeClrFunc(options);
                ^
Error: Unable to compile C# code.
----> Errors when compiling as a CLR library:
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll
' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.d
ll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Po
werPoint.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Office\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Office.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll' could not be f
ound
----> Errors when compiling as a CLR async lambda expression:
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll
' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.d
ll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Po
werPoint.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Office\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Office.dll' could not be found
error CS0006: Metadata file 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop\15.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c\Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.dll' could not be f
ound
    at Error (native)
    at Object.exports.func (D:\Projects\test\node_modules\edge\lib\edge.js:169:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\test\node_modules\node-msoffice-pdf\lib.js:4:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\test\server\api\todo\controller\todo-controller.js:3:14)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\test\server\api\todo\route\todo-route.js:3:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

What's the best way to convert MS Word files to PDF in .Net Core?

Comment: If you don't plan to learn the file formats yourself, I assume you know your first task is to use Google to find an existing library.

Answer (score 0):

This Node.js package doesn't work for the same reason that the .NET Core one doesn't: it's calling `Microsoft.Office.Interop`, and that only works on Windows machines with the Office interop stuff installed.

Basically, when .NET Core compiles it knows that `Microsoft.Office.Interop` might not be available when it's installed, so throws an error then. However JS isn't compiled and finds out at run-time that it's installed on a server/container where `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\...` just isn't there.

Wrapping a Node.js app in your .NET Core just moves this problem from compile-time to run-time.